# Triple spacing in SO text entry

Tags: support, microsoft-edge

This is weird and I'm not sure if it's started happening recently or not.

When I enter an answer on SO, I do so with a single blank line between paragraphs.

Upon editing the answer, I'm seeing *three* blank lines and one between code block lines, bullet lists and so on.

If I revert to the single blank line and save, it runs the two paragraphs together in a single one.

I'm pretty certain this may be an Edge thing since it doesn't happen in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar thing here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345987/extra-lines-are-being-added-when-creating-editing-questions-answers-in-edge

Comment: Thanks, @Mat, upgrading to ChromiumEdge, as per the link you gave, seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Or Edgium, as my team calls it :).